# Can't use rotation effect in clip shape in swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, swiftui, shapes

This i my code:

```
Image()
.resizable()
.scaledToFill()
.frame(width: 200, height: 200)
.clipShape(Rectangle().cornerRadius(8).rotationEffect(.degrees(45)))
```

I receive this error:

> Instance method 'clipShape(_:style:)' requires that 'some View' conform to 'Shape'

Or you know another way to crop my image to diamond?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Diamond shaped clipped image]

Like this?

You can encapsulate the image in a ZStack and rotate them opposite to each other. Then set the frame of the ZStack to match the image. Feel free to ask if anything is unclear!

```
ZStack {
    Image("IMG_1544")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFill()
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(-45))
}
.frame(width: cos(.pi/4) * 200, height: sin(.pi/4) * 200)
.cornerRadius(8)
.rotationEffect(.degrees(45))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use mask instead, maybe it will be enough for your needs, and it accepts views, like

```
Image()
.resizable()
.scaledToFill()
.frame(width: 200, height: 200)
.mask(Rectangle().cornerRadius(8).rotationEffect(.degrees(45))) // << here !!
```